# Determine function and file dependency of a shell script?

Tags: shell

I'm looking for a way of processing a shell script to determine:

1. which commands, scripts or functions are called in the script.
2. which files are accessed by the script (r or w) .

It doesn't need to recurse down through the dependencies, just list what it runs directly. I could probably write something that does this myself but it must have been done before ... I'm just not finding it.

Comment: Interesting question - non-trivial to answer.  Consider tracking output from 'sh -x' (but that only shows you commands that are executed, not those that are not.

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'strace' to run a script and see everything the script and its subprocesses do, including looking for and opening files.  For example:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

touch /tmp/foon
$ chmod +x foo.sh
$ strace -f -e execve,access,open,stat -o foo.trace ./foo.sh
$ cat foo.trace
32176 execve("./foo.sh", ["./foo.sh"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
32176 access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
32176 access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
32176 open("/usr/local/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
32176 execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "./foo.sh"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
...
32177 execve("/usr/bin/touch", ["touch", "/tmp/foon"], [/* 41 vars */]) = 0
32177 open("/tmp/foon", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
...
32176 --- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
$
```

I've trimmed a lot of the other activity going on there (opening system libraries; looking up locale data; and much more).  Check out 'man strace' for details on what the options mean; -f, -o, and -e are the ones I use most often.

Comment: This is good for showing the execution path of a script, but ideally a solution to the OP's question would show unexecuted paths as well (in a way analogous to how `bash -n` checks syntax throughout a script).

Comment: Yes, this is a bit of a problem for me ... there are so many exceptions with different cases sending the scripts to access different files that it gets a bit mind boggling. My main strategy is to use strace and cut down the output to something I can run a diff on to see when things change drastically.

Answer (score 1):

It will be a feature of the [Loker](http://github.com/feuerbach/loker) project which I currently develop. For now, the parser is almost complete and you may implement a reasonable approximation of what you want on top of it. However, in general this task is very complex, because the name of the command may result from variable expansion, field splitting etc.

If you describe what do you need this for and what kind of scripts are you going to parse I will be able to say how much of your needs Loker can satisfy by now.

As alternative option, some versions of bash have `--rpm-requires` option, which also does something similar.

Comment: Very interesting. I will have a better look at Loker when I have time. Properly parsing code for files and executables is quite complex indeed ... I was fantasizing that might be some way to do this by running the code using UNIX to track file access. I don't really know anything about this ... hence the fantasy.

Comment: @mathtick "I was fantasizing that might be some way to do this by running the code using UNIX to track file access." This is definitely possible, use `strace` for this. The problem is you need to actually run code (dynamic vs static analysis) and you won't see all the possible commands/files -- only those which were executed/accessed during this particular run.

Comment: Thanks, that's looks like a good starting point. Also some combination of ptree and pfiles may be a useful starting point for dynamic analysis. The issue of testing all cases (rather than only those that happen to run in a particular instance) is an important one for the code I'm looking at right now.

Answer (score 0):

You just cannot do that in such a dynamic language, your static analysis tool will not be reliable and miss a number of dependencies. Consider the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

func_foo() { echo 'foo running' ; }
func_bar() { echo 'bar running' ; }
# etc...

printf 'foo, bar,...? ' # for testing
read RPC
# rpc_is_in_rpclist "$RPC" || die "invalid call"
printf 'Calling func_%s\n' "$RPC"
func_"$RPC"
```

This is not a convoluted example; I recently added to a production environment a more elaborated version of this with parameters.

If you really need *static* analysis then you should not be using a *dynamic* language in the first place, they are simply incompatible with each other. The same holds for every other functional language where functions are passed as arguments: static analysis cannot practically predict the values of arguments.

Even in a very static and simple language like Java you can still dodge static analysis if you try hard and you use reflection. However reflection is cumbersome by design and not in wide use, so analysis of Java is very useful in practice: see Eclipse etc..

Comment: It's true that you'd want an analysis tool to handle code like you show, but that's not a good design. For maintainability, etc., a `case` statement should be used.

Comment: @Dennis: one reason why people use dynamic languages is because they can code *faster*. For that they are ready to take the risk of less static analysis/verification at compile-time. To be actually implemented faster many scripts would not bother with a heavy-weight case statement. Otherwise their developers would have been using a more static language.