# How to retrieve all tools used in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I've got bunch of shell scripts that used some command and other tools.

So is there a way I can list all programs that the shell scripts are using ? 
Kind of way to retrieve dependencies from the source code.

Comment: Your question is unclear, eg "parse a tool" isn't meaningful.  Are you looking for a list of programs your script used?  Or a list of programs that use your scripts?

Comment: Updated question. I'm looking for the list of programs that uses shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses `sed` to translate pipes and `$(` to newlines, then uses `awk` to output the first word of a line if it might be a command. The pipes into `which` to find potiential command words in the PATH:

```
sed 's/|\|\$(/\n/g' FILENAME | 
awk '$1~/^#/ {next} $1~/=/ {next} /^[[:space:]]*$/ {next} {print $1}' | 
sort -u | 
xargs which 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do it is at run time. You can run bash script in [debug mode](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) with `-x` option and then parse it's output. All executed commands plus their arguments will be printed to standard output.

Comment: bash --rpm-requires does this in more human readable way ... dont you know option to do this without running the script ?

Comment: I don't think you can do it reliably without running the script. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926918/determine-function-and-file-dependency-of-a-shell-script/3928062#3928062) the only tool I found that probably could do it.

Answer (score 1):

While I have no general solution, you could try two approaches:

1. You might use strace to see which programs were executed by your script.
2. You might run your program in a pbuilder environment and see which packages are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Because of dynamic nature of the shell, you cannot do this without running a script.

For example:

```
TASK="cc foo.c"
time $TASK
```

This will be really hard to determine without running that `cc` was called even in such trivial example as above.

In a runtime, you can inspect debug output `sh -x myscript` as pointed out by thiton (+1) and ks1322 (+1). You can also you tool like `strace` to catch all `exec()` syscalls.